# Is it really time?

Tags: code-golf, string, date

A time in the format hhMMss is represented by six numbers in the range 0..9 (e.g.`100203` for 3 seconds after 2 minutes after 10am (10:02.03), or `155603` for three seconds after 56 minutes after 3pm (15:56.03).

Treating these times as integers, these numbers are therefore in the range `000000` to `235959`; but not all numbers in that range are valid times.

Normally, though, integers aren't represented with leading 0s, right?

So, this challenge is to take a numeric input (without leading 0s), and say whether it represents a proper time or not when the leading 0s are put back.

#### Input

Any integer, as a string or an integer type, in the range `0..235959` inclusive. all numbers as strings will be input with no leading 0s (e.g. `2400`, not `002400`). The time `000000` maps to `0`; or [exceptionally as](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8395/is-the-empty-string-an-acceptable-decimal-representation-of-0)  . Inputs outside of this range should return Falsy, but there is no requirement that they are supported.

#### Output

Truthy/Falsy value - by which I mean there must be a consistent distinction in the output between True and False - e.g. True could be output as `1` and False could be any other output (or even a variable output) - as long as it can be documented how to tell what is True and what is not.

#### More Challenge Details

Given the input integer, figure out if the number represents a time (Truthy) or not (Falsy).

A number represents a time if a time (hhMMss) with leading 0s removed is the same as the number.

e.g. 00:00.24 is represented by 24
e.g. 00:06.51 is represented by 651
e.g. 00:16.06 is represented by 1606
e.g. 05:24.00 is represented by 52400
e.g. 17:25.33 is represented by 172533

There are therefore some numbers that can't represent times:

e.g. 7520 - this can't represent hhMMss because 00:75:20 isn't a time

As a general rule, the valid numbers fall into the pattern:

`trimLeadingZeros([00..23][00..59][00..59]);`

*The following numbers are the entire set of inputs and the required answers for this challenge*

**Seconds only (e.g. 00:00.ss, with punctuation and leading 0s removed, -> ss)**
`0 to 59` - Truthy
`60 to 99` - Falsy

**Minutes and seconds (e.g. 00:MM.ss, with punctuation and leading zeros removed, -> MMss)**
`100 to 159` - Truthy
`160 to 199` - Falsy
etc, up to:
`2300 to 2359` - Truthy
`2360 to 2399` - Falsy
`2400 to 2459` - Truthy
`2460 to 2499` - Falsy
etc, up to:
`5900 to 5959` - Truthy
`5960 to 9999` - Falsy

**Hours 0..9, minutes and seconds (e.g. 0h:MM.ss with punctuation and leading zeros removed -> hMMss)**

`10000 to 10059` - Truthy
`10060 to 10099` - Falsy
etc, up to:
`15800 to 15859` - Truthy
`15860 to 15899` - Falsy
`15900 to 15959` - Truthy
`15960 to 19999` - Falsy

`20000 to 20059` - Truthy
`20060 to 20099` - Falsy
`20100 to 20159` - Truthy
`20160 to 20199` - Falsy
etc, up to:
`25800 to 25859` - Truthy
`25860 to 25899` - Falsy
`25900 to 25959` - Truthy
`25960 to 25999` - Falsy
etc, up to:
`95800 to 95859` - Truthy
`95860 to 95899` - Falsy
`95900 to 95959` - Truthy
`95960 to 99999` - Falsy

**Hours 10..23, minutes and seconds (e.g. hh:MM.ss with punctuation and leading zeros removed -> hhMMss)**

`100000 to 100059` - Truthy
`100060 to 100099` - Falsy
`100100 to 100159` - Truthy
`100160 to 100199` - Falsy
etc, up to:
`105800 to 105859` - Truthy
`105860 to 105899` - Falsy
`105900 to 105959` - Truthy
`105960 to 109999` - Falsy

This pattern is then repeated up to:

`235900 to 235959` - Truthy
(`236000 onwards` - Falsy, if supported by program)

Leading 0s must be truncated in the input, if strings are used.

Code golf, so least bytes wins - usual rules apply.

[code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Comment: I just can't find the left-pad built-in ...

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/164439/52210) (the portion about verifying whether a 6-digit number is a valid time)

Comment: You say input is `in the range 0..235959 inclusive`, but then you have a test case for `236000 onwards`. You should clarify what's the actual range of inputs we need to support (I'd suggest 0..999999).

Comment: @Grimmy if your program accepts inputs outside of the range `0..235959` they should be falsy, but the specification doesn't require your program to be able to deal with inputs outside of that range

Comment: It's probably too late now, but I think this challenge would be more fun if the range could be beyond the `235959` and possibly even beyond the `999999`. Now it simply boils down to (in pseudo-code) `max(hh,mm,ss)<60` and we can just ignore the check on hours, since it's guaranteed to be valid.

Comment: Strictly speaking `as long as it can be documented how to tell what is True and what is not` means we can no-op. I believe you really want outputs to be in one of these four pairs: truthy vs falsey; falsey vs truthy; unique value, x vs anything but x; anything but x vs unique value x.

Comment: This is assuming a day with no leap second, or possibly TAI. For example, 2016-12-31 18:59:60 US/Eastern is a valid time.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen yes, you're right, I didn't think that through and it has led to an easier challenge

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [W](https://github.com/A-ee/w), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/A-ee/w/wiki/Code-Page)

Source compression ftw!

```
♀♥@p▒ö
```

Uncompressed:

```
2,a60<A
```

### Explanation

```
2,      % Split number into chunks of length 2
        % The splitting is right-to-left *instead* of left-to-right.
      A % Is all items in the list ...
  a60<  % ... less than 60?
```

Comment: Does `2,` split from right-to-left? If not, wouldn't this fail for an input like `659`, which I assume becomes `[65,9]` instead of `[6,59]`?

Comment: Ah ok, nice, +1 from me in that case. (Your first sentence of your comment is reversed, but your edit in the answer is correct.) Most languages I know would split from left-to-right, so I was surprised to see it works from right-to-left in W. Btw, has there been any word from _Dennis_ when W might be added to TIO? I think this is the third answer I see you post in W.

Answer (score 15):

## Python, <s>45</s> <s>43</s> <s>38</s> 27 bytes

For inputs up until 239999:

```py
lambda n:n/100%100<60>n%100
```

You can [try it online](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSHPKk/f0MBAFYhtzAzs8kCM/wVFmXklGmkaRsaGBmaWmpr/AQ)! Thanks @Jitse and @Scurpulose for saving me several bytes ;)

For inputs above 239999 go with 36 bytes:

```py
lambda n:n/100%100<60>n%100<60>n/4e3
```

Comment: @ElPedro thanks!! :) May be still more golfable

Comment: Also, the Python 2 solution works in Python 3, too. Float instead of int division does not matter.

Comment: Can save some more bytes by using `n/4100` instead of `n/c**2*2.5`. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSFPJ9nW0MDAKjexQiNPNVknTz8ZTJoABTVtzAz@FxRl5pVopGkYGRsamFpqanLBBUwNgABZwMTUEqTiPwA)

Comment: @SurculoseSputum good find! But divide by 4000 then, as 100**2/2.5 = 4000. As variable `c` is now redundant, this can be reduced to `lambda n:max(n%100,n/100%100,n/4e3)<60` for 38 bytes.

Comment: @Jitse Nice golf! For some reason I thought that`245959` was a valid time, hence the `4100` :(

Comment: Note that the the program doesn't have to support input greater than `235959`, so we can do away with the hour check.

Comment: Even keeping the hour check, `lambda n:n%100<60>n/100%100<60>n/4e3` is 2 bytes shorter

Answer (score 8):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>33</s> 25 bytes

*-7 bytes thanks to Kevin Cruijssen*

```perl6
60>*.polymod(100,100).max
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPvfzMBOS68gP6cyNz9Fw9DAQAeINfVyEyv@W3MVFGXmlaQpKKmapSjY2imoFsfkKekoqMTrKNTpATWn5RcpGOgomFrqKJgBaUsgDTIAKAARMgALQoVBHCNjkNR/AA)

Comment: [26 bytes](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/2szALjexQkGvID@nMjc/RcPQwEAHiDVr/xcUZeaVpCkoqZqlKNjaKagWx@Qp6SioxOso1OkB9ablFykY6CiYWuoomAFpSyAN0gsUgAgZgAWhwiCOkTFI6j8A)

Comment: You could also use a regex like some of the other answers for [20 bytes](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/WlHfJtpMT88y1k5PQ09PU0tFv/a/NVdBUWZeSZqCkqpZioKtnYJqcUyeko6CSryOQp0eUF9afpGCgY6CqaWOghmQtgTShgZgAYiQAVgQKgziGBmDpP4DAA)

Answer (score 6):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), <s>1</s>9 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

-10 bytes thanks to Kevin Cruijssen.

Anonymous tacit prefix function. Takes argument as integer.

```apl
⍱59<100∘⊤
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn//1HvRlNLG0MDg0cdMx51Lfmf9qhtwqPevkddzY961zzq3XJovfGjtomP@qYGBzkDyRAPz@D/hgq2CmkKBlwQ2tSAywDMMIMxLC25dHV1odJAo2EsU0uoAkO4UkOgWoiskTFcoZExXKWRMVypkTG6uQiTDQwQZhsYIEw3MEDRY2RqgbDE1AJhi6kFwhpTC7ibLJHUWyKpt0RSbwlWD7ID4WIDAwA)

`100∘⊤` convert **T**o base-100

`59<` are they, each, greater than 59?

`⍱` are none of them true?

Comment: I don't know APL, but can't you save some bytes by checking if the maximum is \$<60\$ after the `100∘⊤`? It halved the byte-counts of both my MathGolf answer and the 05AB1E answer, so I assume it should be able to save some bytes for your solution as well. (Note that the challenge states the valid input is in the range \$[0,235959]\$, so we won't need to check the hours.. I liked the challenge more when a larger range was possible tbh.)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Yes, of course, since we know that we'll never get 240000 or above. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>14</s> <s>13</s> 12 bytes, supports inputs > 235959

```
твR₅0šR12*‹P
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W90eK7NuS3ap@eUVdorKTxqm6SgZF/5/2LThU1Bj5paDY4uDDI00nrUsDPgv87/aEMdMwMdQwMgBtJGxgYgAsQyAbFMgCxTSwMQAVFlACZBbFMLAzAJZluC2SA1RmA1RmA1RgaGYDbYZLB6I7B6I7B6I7B6S7C4JVjcEixuibALQkF4hhCeIZgHsdwAYrsBxHoDiP3GEMONoTwzsHNM4IaBQCwA)

```
тв             # convert input to base 100
  R            # reverse
   ₅           # 255
    0š         # convert to list and prepend 0: [0, 2, 5, 5]
      R        # reverse: [5, 5, 2, 0]
       12*     # times 12: [60, 60, 24, 0]
          ‹    # a < b (vectorizes
           P   # product
```

Comment: You beat me to it. I was just working on an answer. Had already [prepared a test suite](https://tio.run/##RY8xCsJAEEWvEtJmi9lJog4IuYK9WChYWKUQhHRWHsBaG08gmEbs3FLIIXKRdecPYrF//h8e89l2v97stpHDdT70xedy6Jo8G0/nLG@6OH3fCw79eLwNr/Bo00R6LqKLS@8m5DyllyaXpKKuUlclVwupGEVQ9fWMoPACrwyDYTBMHh6XwTN4Bs/gBXvBXrCXf5cNS96SR7JysnayerL@0o6nP9DvCq2@), so feel free to edit it in. XD

Comment: You can shorten the [60, 60, 24] [for 11 bytes](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W90eK7NuS3ap@eUVdorKTxqm6SgZF/5P8jo8JbDax81LLOxkTjc/qhhZ8B/nf/RhjpmBjqGBkAMpI2MDUAEiGUCYpkAWaaWBiACosoATILYphYGYBLMtgSzQWqMwGqMwGqMDAzBbLDJYPVGYPVGYPVGYPWWYHFLsLglWNwSYReEgvAMITxDMA9iuQHEdgOI9QYQ@40hhhtDeWZAA2IB "05AB1E – Try It Online")

Comment: @ExpiredData Although smart, the unprintable isn't part of 05AB1E's codepage, so in that case the entire program should be counted in a different codepage (i.e. UTF-8), and it would only increase. Still a good way to save bytes if the 24 was \$\geq32\$, though.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen why doesn't TIO count it as extra then, like it does with mathematica when using the extended symbols?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen [here's 12 then](https://tio.run/##RY2hDsJAEER/panlxN5e27CBpL9AsAQBCQKFICGtqwKPBovD1aBPkvAR9yPH3SwJYmdnNi87h@Nmu99F9vf5Z5y8b6e@LYtwvhZl28cl@9E/w/DoOvKXWRhei2jiypqGjKU0abOjLNlV2VXJ1UJZlCJo9vWUoPACnxkGw2CYLDw@g2fwDJ7BC@6Cu@Au/y5dmqwmi6TlpO2k9aT9Tp@7X2rSg/UX "05AB1E – Try It Online")

Comment: @ExpiredData Nice 12-byter alternative! :) And TIO only shows UTF-8 encoding correct a.f.a.i.k., for languages which uses UTF-8 like your mentioned Mathematica or Java for example. Any codegolf language with a custom code-page on TIO simply uses the 'SBCS encoding' (which basically means each character is counted as a single byte). I forgot what SBCS stands for, but I thought it was something along the lines of _Single Byte Code Source_ (not sure about the CS part..)

Comment: [6 bytes](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W90eK7NuS3ap@eUVdorKTxqm6SgZF/5/2LThU2HF5gZPGrY@V/nf7ShjpmBjqEBEANpI2MDEAFimYBYJkCWqaUBiICoMgCTILaphQGYBLMtwWyQGiOwGiOwGiMDQzAbbDJYvRFYvRFYvRFYvSVY3BIsbgkWt0TYBaEgPEMIzxDMg1huALHdAGK9AcR@Y4jhxlCeGdCAWAA) I liked this challenge more when inputs above `235959` were allowed as input..

Comment: @KevinCruijssen probably CS stands for *character set*?

Answer (score 5):

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/3/), 35 bytes

```python
f=lambda n:n<1or(n%100<60)*f(n/100)
```

A recursive function which returns `1` or `True` (which are truthy) if valid or `0` (which is falsey) if not.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVLBTsMwDL3zFb6gJVDASZtqmbZ9BD@AiljHpC0dXXdA0769pLGdil5q@/n5OU8@/w7fXSiX534c282xOX1@NRBWYW26XoVHg7iuUT@1KrzFWI9t10Pbd6ePAoYODgGUwgKc1wWoOkY@RbG1AENVM5UN1W05AbZ0nNUpY6xKWMVYlbCKMOcxqTjOSClrJTVEJ3lNOeNuSdssneQ15YJ73lZwzxvzXjTfynxL863Mt2gIN4IbwuXNpG9F35K@FX1L@lb0LenHH@Ge@F74nvhe@J74Xvh@tmf2hwyZHRKLMPcY7jG5x3CPkR42ErOTyFZi9hLZTMxuItuJ2c@SH1ymHr16gPhdw@HnunvfXa7H4QIbuMWL0zBdW5iurG/Cfqfmw3sGo@@JeO4PYVCLCYLbalvfJ5iCly3c7ovXOOTUDDO5@C@m9fgH)** *

#### How?

`True` and `False` are equivalent to `1` and `0` respectively in Python.

The function (`f=lambda n:...`) checks that the last up-to-two digits as an integer (`n%100`) are less than sixty (`<60`), chops them off (`n/100`) and multiplies by a recursive call `*f(...)` until an input of zero is reached (`n<1or`) at which point `True` is returned. If at any stage the check fails a `False` is placed in the multiplication, which will then evaluate to `0` (a falsey value).

---

* Only `f(0)` evaluates to `True`, but `set((True, 1, 1, ..., 1))` evaluates to `{True}` due to the equivalence of `True` and `1` in Python.

Answer (score 5):

## Java 8, 38 bytes

```java
n->n%100<60&n%1e4<6e3&n%1e6<24e4&n<1e6
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY8xT8MwEIXn5lfcQmUPsUKbRmoTOoAYGFjIiBhMcgQHx47sSyGq@tuDSQYGxPTe3TvdfdfKk4zb@mNSXW8dQRtqMZDS4kma2nZ59Cfw5FB2opzl//zOao0VWefzKKq09B4epTJwjlb98KpVBZ4kBTlZVUMXIhZWKtOAdI1/fuFwhmi1WjDABYEbMPgJS4fxPKQLhGjQoJOEjHGIj/OwMPhFD4bYZrvb7/acC606Rew6SbioFjb2yygaZ4c@XL8d2WTio7kKg0WWrIPBtMhwO7us2KSYrk0R7BR2oiE3lkiMizfr7mX1zsrRE3bCDnQ49OEf0uYH9RJdpm8)

Basically an improvement of @Kevin Cruijssen's solution; I don't have enough reputation for a comment.

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, <s>27</s> <s>22</s> 18 bytes

*Saved 4 bytes when @NahuelFouilleul pointed out that it doesn't need to be a look-ahead in the regex*

```perl
$_=!/[6-9].(..)*$/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3lZRP9pM1zJWT0NPT1NLRf//f0MLIy4jY1NLU8t/@QUlmfl5xf91fU31DAwN/usW5AAA)

Since the input is guaranteed to be less than 236000, the hours can be ignored as they will always be valid.  This pattern match checks if there is a 6, 7, 8, or 9 in the tens digit of the minutes or seconds.  The match is then negated to get truthy for valid dates and falsy for invalid ones.

Comment: what about [18 bytes](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3lZRP9pM1zJWT0NPT1NLRf//f0MLIy4jY1NLU8t/@QUlmfl5xf91fU31DAwN/usW5AAA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>13</s> 7 bytes

```
bȷ2<60Ạ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY27DYNAEEQbIphbPvJK5PRhiQRdA6RO3IYLcG4JkSEktwGNLLezAcHNzoyebqYx59ns@f9J3@FYPrav2/t8fQczVB2qhPLKlRou7hp3TXGtwiUoUN23D1Dpld4ZISNkBImeP5MX8kJeyCt7Za/s9d6KEylFSkwxjlhHzCP2a08X)

A monadic link taking an integer and returning `1` for true and `0` for false.

Thanks to @KevinCruijsen for saving 6 bytes!

Comment: I don't know Jelly, but based on that `“<<ð‘` (which I think is `[60,60,24]`?) you can probably save some bytes with a different approach: convert to base 100 as list, get the maximum, check if it's smaller than 60. (In pseudo-code: `max(hh,mm,ss)<60`.) The range is guaranteed to be \$[0,235959]\$.

Comment: Posted a couple of different sevens too.

Answer (score 4):

## [LibreOffice Calc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QvapB.png), 43 bytes

```
=MAX(MOD(A1,100),MOD(A1/100,100),A1/4e3)<60
```

Basically a <s>blatant rip-off</s> respectful port of @RGS excellent Python answer so go and upvote them. Only posted as I have not seen a LibreOffice Calc answer on here before and I was messing about while calculating my tax return this evening (code golf is much more fun). Screenshot of some test cases below.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 12 bytes

```
[6-9].(..)?$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PZGxDsJADEP3@w6QykDlpL0TmRj5CIQEAwMLA@L/j4tdsVQ@x3qJ1c/z@3o/@n663Pu1HeM2T/N8OO96R6lRGkpEMaDYeNl42nj7MgxfaqqWKr01vTW9Nb11eDWQlJqKJLGSBlTqRp1@PXHLqVI3avqh7fRDF@Q@cpwcJ8fJcRh9o2/0eTP5Tr6T7@Q7@U6@kz@@ww/mg/lgPpgP5oP5@NfaerHM1myrBs1MM9PMNDPOVBxqDlWHukPlofZQfaj/osMXXT7@A/AD) Link includes test cases. Accepts input from `0` to `239999` and outputs `0` for times, `1` for non-times. Explanation: Simply checks whether the second or fourth last digit is greater than `5`.

Answer (score 3):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup><s>32</s></sup> <sup><s>26</s></sup> <sup><s>23</s></sup> 16 bytes

```
60*/ .>100#.inv]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY@xDsIwDET3foUFQwUq4ZLIVVypLEhMTOxMiAoYYOvvh6hiiM3g4aS757tXXrl2onGgljoCDeV2jo6X8yn32O7JHTywds/3fM2b5n57fMjTSBOhFvxTWFSvlEhTWwtOSZba7HXWi9TmEHU4RJ0OUcdD/H9u3gOmAGAqAAYSOJkanEwPTqYIJ71ELEMsQyxDFoadWyj5Cw)

*-16 bytes (!!) thanks to Adam.  This new solution uses the approach from [his APL answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200094/43319) so be sure to upvote that.*

Convert the input to base 100, check that all digits are less than 60.

Note the most significant digit is guaranteed to be less than 24 by the allowed inputs.

Comment: Can you not combine `[:*/` and `>` into `*/ .>` ?

Comment: No need to stringify. You can take the argument as a string.

Comment: Re: your first comment, you can indeed and it's cool observation but doesn't change the byte count.  I'll change per your 2nd comment in a sec.

Comment: 26: `24 60 60*/ .>_3{.100&#.inv` [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY@xCgJBDER7v2JQ8FB0ze6aY3NwNoKVlT9gIR5qoZ2NH78uh8UmQlIMzLxMHnnqmgF9hwYrELqya4f96XjIYYuWyiw3cLtz/DhPNJ@5@/OdF5Pr5faCR48BVAv@KRpVq5TIpLYWnJIstdnrrBepzSHqcIg6HaKOh/h/3JwnMgWITAUiAwmcTA1OpgcnU4ST/kQsQyxDLENGhn23UPIX "J – Try It Online")

Comment: Very nice, I like that much better than my original approach.  Thanks Adam!

Comment: You're welcome. It is simply a port of [mine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200094/43319).

Comment: 23: `24 60 60*/ .>(3$100)&#:` [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY/BCsJADETv/YpBxVrRms26ZbNQL4InT/6CtIgX//@0LsXDJkJyGJh5mbzzqm9njAktDiCkssce18f9lvmMgcrsT@gvO79xRN12nXLXTM/XBw4jZlAtwk/RogalRJraWmBKBqnNTmedSG1mr8PsdZq9jrP/P27OE5kCRKYCkYFwiKZGiKZHiKZIiPoTsQyxDLEMWRj23ULJXw "J – Try It Online")

Comment: 16: `60*/ .>100#.inv]` [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY@xDsIwDET3foUFQwUq4ZLIVVypLEhMTOxMiAoYYOvvh6hiiM3g4aS757tXXrl2onGgljoCDeV2jo6X8yn32O7JHTywds/3fM2b5n57fMjTSBOhFvxTWFSvlEhTWwtOSZba7HXWi9TmEHU4RJ0OUcdD/H9u3gOmAGAqAAYSOJkanEwPTqYIJ71ELEMsQyxDFoadWyj5Cw "J – Try It Online")

Comment: Ah because the input constraint gives us the 24, nice!

Answer (score 3):

## Java 8, <s>45</s> 43 bytes

```java
n->n%100<60&n%1e4/100<60&n%1e6/1e4<24&n<1e6
```

Improved by [*@Joja*'s Java answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200131/52210) by removing the divisions, so make sure to upvote him/her as well!

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##TVFBbsIwELzzihVSUaKEsDYBNST0B6UHjoiDCaFyCgYRQ1WhvD1dr0FwGc@sxzv2ulZXNay3P125V00Dn0qbWw9AG1udd6qsYOEkwNemrkoLZUA7YMKcim2PoLHK6hIWYGAOnRl@mDeBWExxQKRKRy9iOqJCIdOBKUh0uTt@umz2dPze5XrUWzjQFYKlPWvzvVqDCn3@7njmaA0zMNWvu@BqfRPxFGOKiAWtcowOHEsdS4lNMnTgXcjo@OQdGZlnzJ1HskeyR6Jgzp3ZL9kv2S/Zn3E943rG9eyZ5RevhFeClQ9Hn44@Hn3@2DenN@CjC7YhD@A5gno@FDnUxdxhFD22AZZ/ja0OyfFikxONz@5NoKM66s@gH5mkdCK8/1zb/QM)

**Explanation:**

```java
n->              // Method with integer parameter and boolean return-type
  n%100<60       //  Check whether the seconds are smaller than 60
  &n%1e4/100<60  //  and the minutes are smaller than 60
  &n%1e6/1e4<24  //  and the hours are smaller than 24
  &n<1e6         //  and the entire number is smaller than 1,000,000
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 11 bytes

```
‹⌈⍘Ｎ⭆¹⁰⁰℅ι<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMMntbhYwzexIjO3NFfDKbE4NbgEKJ6u4ZlXUFriV5qblFqkoamjABH1TSzQMDQw0FFwBpqSmFwClMvUBAIdBSUbJU1N6///jYxNLU0t/@uW5QAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Accepts input from `0` to `239999` and outputs a Charcoal boolean, `-` for times, no output for non-times. Explanation:

```
     ¹⁰⁰    Literal 100
    ⭆       Map over implicit range and join
         ι  Current index
        ℅   Unicode character with that ordinal
   Ｎ        Input as a number
  ⍘         Convert to string using string as base
 ⌈          Character with highest ordinal
‹           Is less than
          < Character with ordinal 60
            Implicitly print
```

`BaseString` always returns `0` for a value of `0` (bug?) but fortunately this is still less than `<`.

Alternative solution, also 11 bytes:

```
⌈⍘Ｎ⭆¹⁰⁰›ι⁵⁹
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM3sSIztzRXwymxODW4BCiUruGZV1Ba4leam5RapKGpowAR9U0s0DA0MNBRcC9KTSwBymTqKJhaaoKA9f//RsamlqaW/3XLcgA) Link is to verbose version of code. Accepts input from `0` to `239999` and outputs `0` for times, `1` for non-times. Explanation:

```
    ¹⁰⁰     Literal 100
   ⭆        Map over implicit range and join
        ι   Current index
       ›    Greater than
         ⁵⁹ Literal 59
  Ｎ         Input as a number
 ⍘          Convert to a string using string as base
⌈           Maximum
            Implicitly print
```

`BaseString` doesn't require the string base to have distinct characters, so this string just has 60 `0`s and 40 `1`s.

Unfortunately taking the base numerically returns an empty list for an input of zero, which takes an extra three bytes to handle, pushing the byte count above 11. But fortunately I can substitute an acceptable non-zero number in only two bytes, so another 11-byte alternative is possible:

```
›⁶⁰⌈↨∨Ｎχ¹⁰⁰
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMO9KDWxJLVIw8xAR8E3sSIztzRXwymxOFXDv0jDM6@gtMSvNDcJKK@po2BoACYMNIHA@v9/I2NTS1PL/7plOQA) Link is to verbose version of code. Accepts input from `0` to `239999` and outputs a Charcoal boolean, `-` for times, no output for non-times. Explanation:

```
 ⁶⁰         Literal 60
›           Is greater than
      Ｎ     Input as a number
     ∨      Logical Or
       χ    Predefined variable `10`
    ↨   ¹⁰⁰ Convert to base 100 as a list
   ⌈        Maximum
            Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Turing Machine Code](https://github.com/MilkyWay90/Turing-Machine-But-Way-Worse), <s>336</s> 548 bytes

Prints 't' for true and 'f' for false.

```
0 * * r !
! * * r "
! _ _ l b
b * _ l t
" * * r £
" _ _ l c
c * * l c
c _ _ r 4
£ * * r $
£ _ _ l d
d * * l d
d _ _ r 3
$ * * r ^
$ _ _ l e
e * * l e
e _ _ r 2
^ * * r &
^ _ _ l g
g * * l g
g _ _ r 1
& * * l &
& _ _ l O
O 1 1 r a
O 2 2 r 1
O * * * f
a * * r 2
1 0 0 r 2
1 1 1 r 2
1 2 2 r 2
1 3 3 r 2
1 * * * f
2 0 0 r 3
2 1 1 r 3
2 2 2 r 3
2 3 3 r 3
2 4 4 r 3
2 5 5 r 3
2 * * * f
3 * * r 4
4 0 0 r t
4 1 1 r t
4 2 2 r t
4 3 3 r t
4 4 4 r t
4 5 5 r t
4 * * * f
f * * l f
f _ _ r n
n * _ r n
n _ f * halt
t * * l t
t _ _ r y
y * _ r y
y _ t r halt
```

[Try it online!](http://morphett.info/turing/turing.html?e0baa286625720d3ac74f1152ded6589)

*Added a chunk of bytes thanks to @Laikoni for spotting my misread of the question.*

Comment: Looks like this fails for hours >2, e.g. `30000` returns `f` though it is a valid time.

Comment: Upon closer inspection, it looks like you require leading zeros, as e.g. `3` fails but `000003` does not. However, the point of the challenge is that no leading zeros are given.

Comment: @Laikoni, Thanks, I read through that too quickly and thought it simply meant I had to handle leading zeros, not actually imply them myself in the input myself. I'll sort it out....

Comment: As friendly competition, I also gave it a shot: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200153/56433. To keep the byte count down, I took a rather liberal approach to indicate true or false, though this is usually fine for challenge on this site.

Answer (score 3):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://bitbucket.org/ngn/k), <s>14</s> 9 bytes

-5 bytes thanks to ngn

```
*/60>100\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNS8/7/z/NSkvfzMDO0MAg5n@auqWlgqEpEFsYKBgZmxooWFqCRSxAYgYgzn8A)

Based on [Adám's APL solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200094/75681) and Kevin Cruijssen's suggestion.

Comment: `0=` -> `~` and rm `{` `x}`

Comment: @ngn Thanks, I always seem to forget about negation.

Comment: negation could be pushed to the comparison: `*/60>100\ ` turning `+` into `*` (or ∨ into ∧) like in [de morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)

Comment: @ngn Yes, it's very useful!

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 7 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
ìL e<60
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=7EwgZTw2MA&input=MjM1OTU5)

Comment: I love an answer in Japt! I've just noticed that this will fail on anything where the hour is between `24` and `59`.

Answer (score 3):

## x86-16, IBM PC DOS, <del>46</del>  <del>44</del>  39 bytes

```
00000000: d1ee 8a0c ba30 4c88 5401 03f1 4ed1 e9fd  .....0L.T...N...
00000010: b303 ad86 e0d5 0a4b 7502 b628 3ac6 7d02  .......Ku..(:.}.
00000020: e2f0 d6b4 4ccd 21                        ....L.!
```

Build and test `ISTIME.COM` with `xxd -r`.

**Unassembled listing:**

```
D1 EE       SHR  SI, 1              ; SI = 80H
8A 0C       MOV  CL, BYTE PTR[SI]   ; CX = input length
BA 4C30     MOV  DX, 4C30H          ; DH = 60+16, DL = '0'
88 54 01    MOV  BYTE PTR[SI+1], DL ; 'zero' pad byte to the left of input
03 F1       ADD  SI, CX             ; SI to end of input string
4E          DEC  SI                 ; remove leading space from length
D1 E9       SHR  CX, 1              ; CX = CX / 2
FD          STD                     ; read direction downward
B3 03       MOV  BL, 3              ; counter to test if third iteration (meaning hours)
        LOD_LOOP:
AD          LODSW                   ; AX = [SI], SI = SI - 2
86 E0       XCHG AH, AL             ; endian convert
D5 0A       AAD                     ; binary convert
4B          DEC  BX                 ; decrement count
75 02       JNZ  COMP               ; if not third time through, go compare
B6 28       MOV  DH, 40             ; if third, set test to 24+16
        COMP:
3A C6       CMP  AL, DH             ; is number less than DL?
7D 02       JGE  NOT_VALID          ; if not, it's invalid
E2 F0       LOOP LOD_LOOP           ; otherwise keep looping
        NOT_VALID: 
D6          SALC                    ; Set AL on Carry
B4 4C       MOV  AH, 4CH            ; return to DOS with errorlevel in AL
CD 21       INT  21H                ; call DOS API
```

A standalone PC DOS executable.  Input via command line, output DOS exit code (errorlevel) `255` if Truthy `0` if Falsy.

**I/O:**

Truthy:

[image]

Falsy:

[image]

Thanks to @PeterCordes for:

- -2 bytes use DOS exit code for Truthy/Falsy result
- -3 bytes eliminate ASCII conversion before `AAD`

Comment: Isn't `[SI+1]` (81h) the first byte of the arg string that you're overwriting?  I would have thought you'd want to store to `[si]` and just replace the length byte with `'0'` padding.

Comment: @PeterCordes `[80h]` is the length byte and `[81h]` is the char (can only be a space (`20H`) or a forward slash) between the command invocation and the start of the command line argument string that starts at `[82h]`.

Comment: Ah, https://cs.lmu.edu/~ray/notes/x86assembly/ and [How to pass/retrieve DOS command-line parameters in a 16-bit assembly program?](//stackoverflow.com/a/41448997) weren't clear about that.  Makes sense now, I'd forgotten that DOS allowed a non-whitespace separator between command and args.

Comment: Yes, it's quite annoying really because that leading space is counted in the length byte, so you pretty much always have to decrement that before you can use it.

Comment: You're spending a bunch of bytes to check that hours <= 24.  The problem statement in the question guarantees that the max integer is 23... so you can make a version that only solves that simpler problem.  Also, I think your code will accept repeated hours pairs, like `23230000`, so not arbitrary integer.  You could just check the tens digits (AH) for being `<= '5'` in the loop, instead of `aad` those bytes into a binary integer.  (And BTW, I think you can skip the `sub ax, '00'` before AAD: `10*0x30 + 0x30 = 0x210`, so you just need to check that the AAD result in AL is < 60+16 or 24+16).

Comment: Can you use a non-zero exit status instead of printing a `'0/1'` to save bytes?  At least the `ret` could go.

Comment: @PeterCordes yeah, I know I could shave off a few bytes not making it callable and not a standalone DOS .com, just return a `ZF` or `CF`.  What stopped me was having to refactor everything when I couldn't count on being able to overwrite `input string pointer - 1` with the zero pad.  I think the only way to return an exit code is to use `INT 21H` / `AH=4CH` (a lot more bytes).  Give me a bit to digest your previous post and see what we can squeeze out!

Comment: I didn't mean a function, I meant a DOS program that exits with [`int 21h/ah=4Ch`](http://spike.scu.edu.au/~barry/interrupts.html#ah4c) with an exit status of AL = 0 or -1 (from `salc` = Set AL from Carry - a 1-byte (undocumented) instruction that's like `sbb al,al` without writing flags).  That should save 2 bytes net: drop the `ret` and turn the 2-byte `adc` into 1-byte `salc`.  Code-golf answers don't even have to be fully portable, and salc works in 16 and 32-bit mode on at least every Intel CPU including current ones.

Comment: @PeterCordes brilliant idea eliminating the ASCII conversion before `AAD` in this case!  That never would have occurred to me that it would work in this case!  I've changed it to return a DOS exit code instead of output to console. So odd that `SALC` would be left in all chips and not documented, wonder why? Thanks as always!

Comment: @PeterCordes you said the code will accept repeated hour pairs.  Is that a problem?  Rules state input will be only in the range of `0..235959` so shouldn't have to handle `23230000` right?

Comment: re: 23232323: it's not a problem per-se, but if you're spending extra bytes to apply a tight bound for hours, it might not make sense if you don't catch other too-high-number problems.  (You could look at it as formatting error vs. semantic error, though.)  Re: undocumented opcodes: perhaps an extremely conservative approach to maintaining backwards compat with possible existing binaries?  That was Agner Fog's guess in his [Stop the Instruction Set War](https://www.agner.org/optimize/blog/read.php?i=25) article.

Answer (score 2):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 63 bytes

```
f: func[n][either n % 100 > 59[return 0][if n > 1[f n / 100]]1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYsxDgIxDAS/sjqJEpEggjBFHkFruUB3ji5NQJbv/SGh2Slm1nTrL91Y0MsT5WgrN2Gtvquh4YQYAjISsakf1hCEaxkmI/LkZRYiUXr5mL7XHQ6OiXC9jedwNDc9wv0PIuGv1ebsWM55QYGL9B8)

Of course the recursive function with integers is much shorter than the below version that works on strings.

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), <s>139</s> <s>130</s> 115 bytes

```
func[s][s: pad/left/with s 6 #"0"
not any collect[foreach n collect[loop 3[keep to 1 take/part s 2]][keep n > 60]]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYxBCoMwFET3nmJI18VoqzQuPES3IYsQExRDEuIvxdPbgG1Xb5hhXrbT8bSTVJUbcLhXMHJTchuQ9FR766h@LzRjQ48L46wKkaDDDhO9t4aki9lqMyP8Gx9jwk2u1iZQRAPSq62TzlQsrVLnEjCi50qp42cgSNZ0goG1d84LGs7Fye7B@28QgimZ8hJImpj28mLXkcGBiuoD)

Comment: I don't know Red, but you can probably save some bytes by checking if the maximum after the `[s: pad/left/with s 6 #"0"
t: collect[loop 3[keep to 1 take/part s 2]]]` is smaller than 60.

Comment: @Kevin Cruijssen Red's `max` function takes exactly 2 arguments and doesn't work on lists.

Comment: Ah ok. Yeah, Java is the same unfortunately. It would only increase the byte-count instead of decreasing it. :)

Answer (score 2):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), <s>18</s> 9 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
◄+░2/i╙╟<
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##PZIxTgQxDEX7nIKeAtuZhLHEUZDQNgtIIBqOwAUoFkTF3eYig/08osko/l/@P2/39fT@9Pj2ct4fru737fvjevv6tJvn7fKzXX7v9l2aNmvD25Q2tbk3lZiJNo2hxlRjbBaC9VDiiGsfeZ15TbWnuqS6pLqkuqS6hDrWUIeHGkdcfeR15pXAiiRUMlZkMJlMZha5Tc9Y0xNnTtbBZDLBs@JxPF718TiejFKyjCwjy8gysoysOPEoHsWjeBQPMOhj9DH6GH2MPkYfo4/Rx@hj9DH6WD2dPc4eZ4@zx9nj7HH2OHucPc4eZ4//IzwYFsSieGA8OAJSeF186jfmffkpp5ZTcRZzKehS1KWwS3GXAi9FXgq9FHsp@FL0hZrxp4FJLyi9qPR0/gE)

**Explanation:**

```python
◄+        # Add builtin 10,000,000 to the (implicit) input-integer
  ░       # Convert it to a string
   2/     # Split it into parts of size 2: [10,hh,mm,ss]
     i    # Convert each to an integer
      ╙   # Pop and push the maximum
       ╟< # And check if it's smaller than builtin 60
          # (after which the entire stack joined together is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), <s>50</s> <s>48</s> 46 bytes

*-2 bytes each thanks to @kanine and @l4m2*

```javascript
a=>a.padStart(6,0).match(/../g).every(x=>x<60)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/ifk1qikGb7P9HWLlGvIDEluCSxqETDTMdAUy83sSQ5Q0NfT08/XVMvtSy1qFKjwtauwsbMQPN/QVFmXolGmoaSkbGppamlkqamtQIXkqCZgZkBSPA/AA)

Comment: Doesn't this fail for e.g. `60000`?

Comment: Yeah you're right @Neil thanks

Comment: you can replace the quoted '0' to just 0

Comment: Doesn't this fail for, say, `240000`, as `24` isn't a valid hour?

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms no since the domain is 0 - 239999.. so an input of 240000 is undefined for the challenge

Comment: Why do you need `\d`? It's anyway an integer, every char is `\d`

Answer (score 2):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), <s>33</s> 32 bytes

```bash
p=%100\<60;echo $[$1$p&$1/100$p]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/v8BW1dDAIMbGzMA6NTkjX0ElWsVQpUBNxVAfKKxSEPv//39DU0tTSwA)

Input is passed as an argument.

Output is 0 (falsey) or 1 (truthy).

(I've deleted an earlier 45-byte version that used egrep.]

Answer (score 2):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 28 bytes

```sh
e=%100/60;(($1$e||$1/100$e))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fU/RCoMwDHzPVwiL2MKG7UYFN50fIj7IqHQgG0wfxtRv77oYX5eH5HrXHLnP4HwnpPC2jLVSaaYuQqBGO8@o08CgldLbm3tGWIEE6CIqxcDkKwg/V5AzYxgEgaTjiRhySkqqhD2yzSxnM7MyYYRVsO/7CLCL2n60r0c72uEMQrgyOO9Rxy7cTMc6glLCLwCH2VLwk8Q/m0VR4IST6OusqVUj9RJXVaEO5sp98V8)

Returns via exit code.

Since `$parameters` are expanded before `((arithmetic))`, $e expands to `%100/60` before arithmetic is done.

There are 2 other 28 byte solutions I found as well, albeit not as interesting:

```sh
((h=100,$1%h/60||$1/h%h/60))
```

```sh
(($1%100/60||$1/100%100/60))
```

Answer (score 2):

## T-SQL, <s>42</s> 41 bytes

Saved 1 byte thanks to @Neil

Supports all positive integer input

Returns 1 for true, 0 for false

```sql
DECLARE @ INT=235959

PRINT-1/~(@/240000+@/100%100/60+@%100/60)
```

Comment: Does `@/240000` not work?

Comment: @Neil it sure would. I wonder how I missed it. Thanks a lot much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)], 26 bytes

```javascript
f=>!/[6-9].(..)?$/.test(f)
```

Simple Javascript Regular Expression

JavaScript (Node.js) – [Try It Online](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNFNSkxKzdHNy09J/f@/xDbN1k5RP9pM1zJWT0NPT9NeRV@vJLW4RCNN839yfl5xfk6qXk5@ukaJhoGmJheqiKWphaUlpiimkAk2MVNs6kywCWJVaYYpaGSMU9gUm7AZWPg/AA)

Comment: You've got a stray space after the `>`, I think you can use `.` instead of `\d`, and you can probably simplify the condition, e.g. by using `test`.

Comment: Thanks @Neil, I used test, but changed the logic.

Comment: You don't use recursive so you can omit `t=`

Answer (score 2):

## [Turing Machine Simulator](http://morphett.info/turing/turing.html), <s>299</s> <s>272</s> 269  bytes

```
0 _ _ l 1
0 * * r 0
1 * _ l 2
* _ t * t
2 6 f * f
2 7 f * f
2 8 f * f
2 9 f * f
2 * _ l 3
3 * _ l 4
4 6 f * f
4 7 f * f
4 8 f * f
4 9 f * f
4 * _ l 5
5 0 _ l 6
5 1 _ l 6
5 2 _ l 6
5 3 _ l 6
5 * _ l 7
6 _ t * t
6 1 t * t
6 2 t * t
6 * f * f
7 _ * * t
7 1 _ * t
7 * f * f
```

[Run in Turing Machine Simulator](http://morphett.info/turing/turing.html?073d1e0b9d119d1e74708bcb2957d99d).
Halts with `t` on the tape for true inputs and a prefix of the input and `f` for false inputs.

Comment: Yeah I tend to pontificate a bit with my true/false outputs. This is nice, very succinct. I only too briefly considered the idea of starting at the end of the input.

Answer (score 2):

## VBA, 177 bytes

```
Sub a()
x=1: i=""
If Len(i)<6 Then Do Until Len(i)=6: i="0"&i: Loop
s = Right(i, 2): m = Left(Right(i,4),2): h = Left(i,2)
If s>59 Or m>59 Or h>23 Then x=0
Debug.Print s
End Sub
```

Works for values above 235959, assigns x to output 1 or 0 with input as i

Comment: You can replace the `If` and `Do Until` with `Do While` which will check the condition before the loop even starts. I don't specifically know VBA but does it not have some sort of function declaration? Normally answers are required to be either functions or full programs that include I/O (Input, Print etc.)

Comment: It does have function declaration, yeah. I'll edit my answer to follow the rules. Thank you!

Comment: Hi there and Welcome to PPCG! I recommend that you take a look at our [Tips for Golfing in VBA](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/5175/61846) for some hints on how to get your code even shorter, and for some general rules on input and out as they relate to VBA (VBA is weird to the [rules](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/114126/61846) are [weird](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14421/61846))

Comment: As it stands, unfortunately, your response is not quite valids, as it does not properly take input (see rules above), but it is functionally correct.

Comment: If you use our tips and some tricks, like removing whitespace, using integer division, abbreviate the print statement, use `Right("000000"&i,6)` and use the `mid` function instead of the `left` and `right` calls for calculating `m`, you can get your solution way down in size. With vanilla VBA, you can get down to 85 bytes w/ `Sub a(i):v=Right("000000"&i,6):Debug.?v\1E4<24*(Mid(v,3,2)<60)*(v Mod 100<60):End Sub` and if you use an Excel VBA immediate window function you can get down to 65 as `v=Right("000000"&[A1],6):?v\1E4<24*(Mid(v,3,2)<60)*(v Mod 100<60)`

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 76 bytes

supports ***any*** number

```
!FreeQ[FromDigits/@Join@@@IntegerDigits/@Tuples[Range/@{24,6,10,6,10}-1],#]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n277X9GtKDU1MNqtKD/XJTM9s6RY38ErPzPPwcHBM68kNT21CCYaUlqQk1ocHZSYl56q71BtZKJjpmNoACZqdQ1jdZRj1f4HFGXmlSg4pEcbGZtamlrG/v8PAA)

Answer (score 1):

## T-SQL, 64 bytes

```sql
SELECT*FROM t WHERE 60>LEFT(RIGHT('000'+v,4),2)AND 60>RIGHT(v,2)
```

Input is taken from pre-existing table *t* with varchar field *v*, [per our input standards](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/5341#5341).

Outputs 1 row (with the original value) for "true", and 0 rows for "false".

Accepts only values in the specified range (`0` to `235959`), so doesn't validate the first 2 digits.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>90</s> 85 bytes

```python
lambda t:{t}&s
s={0}
import time
while len(s)<86400:s|={int(time.strftime("%H%M%S"))}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaHEqrqkVq2Yq9i22qCWKzO3IL@oRKEkMzeVqzwjMydVISc1T6NY08bCzMTAwKq4xrY6M69EAySvV1xSlAZiaCipeqj6qgYraWrW/i8oAsmnaRhoanLB2GaoHANkrpGxqaWppabmfwgDAA)

The idea is to simply create a set of all valid time (as int), then check if the given number is in the set. The set is created by repeatedly adding the current time to the set until all `86400` distinct values are added.
Returns: non-empty set if `t` is valid time, otherwise empty set.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>27 26</s>  21 bytes

Takes input as an integer in `hhmmss` format. Returns \$0\$ or \$1\$.

```javascript
n=>n%100<60&n%1e4<6e3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/P1i5P1dDAwMbMQA3ISDWxMUs1/p@cn1ecn5Oql5OfrpGmYWhpYGZsqqnJhSpsZGxqaWqJRdjQyMwQi7CZgaGRpuZ/AA)

#### How?

```javascript
n=>n%100<60&n%10000<6000
```

is just as long as:

```javascript
n=>n%100<60&n/100%100<60
```

But from there we can use the scientific notation to save 3 bytes:

```javascript
n%10000<6000
n%1e4<6e3
```

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Babel Node)](https://babeljs.io/), <s>71</s> 52 bytes

```javascript
t=i=>{[,,m,,s]=(i+'').padStart(6,0);return m<6&&s<6}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNFNSkxKzdHNy09J/f@/xDbT1q46WkcnV0enONZWI1NbXV1TryAxJbgksahEw0zHQNO6KLWktChPIdfGTE2t2Mas9n9yfl5xfk6qXk5@ukaJhoGmJheqiKWphaWlpuZ/AA)

Comment: [48 bytes](https://tio.run/##VchBCoMwEADAuw@pu3QNXhoaNH7CoxRcNZSUaMQs@X56do7z48xpvfwpzcKLC80RN1fEFm8HlznAPBHtROljwT/rGtXJ2yh8CWhqsdt7/Ui9nrGs8UgxOBXiFwRaxOo@5vU2BrH8AQ "JavaScript (Babel Node) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 60 bytes

```php
<?=preg_match('#\d+([01]\d|2[0-3])([0-5]\d){2}#',$argn+1e6);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt62oCg1PT43sSQ5Q0NdOSZFWyPawDA2JqXGKNpA1zhWE8jVNQXyNauNapXVdVQSi9LztA1TzTSt//83Mja1NLXkMjI2g1BcRiZQAQPDf/kFJZn5ecX/dd0A)

Basically regex and not much golfable, but fun. Inputs above 235959 are indeterminate.

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 44 bytes

```
#&@@TimeObject[x=IntegerDigits[#,100,3]]==x&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2ar8V9ZzcEhJDM31T8pKzW5JLrC1jOvJDU9tcglMz2zpDhaWcfQwEDHODbW1rZC7b@mNZdGQFFmXomDVpqmvgNXNZeBDpcZEIMUcRmCWEbGBmASzDYBs01AbFNLAzAJVW0AocA8UwsDCAXhWUJ4QJVctf8B)

Works for values above `235959`!

The built-in `TimeObject` command can automatically round up each element!

#### Explanation

```
x=IntegerDigits[#,100,3]
```

Split input in base-100 (i.e. in chunks of 2 digits), padded to length 3. Store that list in `x`.

```
TimeObject[...]
```

Convert that to a `TimeObject`.

```
#&@@...
```

Extract the rounded string

```
...==x
```

Check if that is equal to `x` (i.e. nothing rounded up).

### The boring version, 28 bytes

```
Max@IntegerDigits[#,100]<60&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2ar8d83scLBM68kNT21yCUzPbOkOFpZx9DAINbGzEDtv6Y1l0ZAUWZeiYNWmqa@A1c1l4EOlxkQA1UACRDLyNgATILZJmC2CYhtamkAJqGqDSAUmGdqYQChIDxLCA@okqv2PwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 30 bytes

```c
f(n){n=n%100<60&n/100%100<60;}
```

Doesn't check hours.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZDBboMwDIbveQorE1Oi0tUtoxIDttueYLeOQ2VgjdSFKYRJXcWzs8A6mvri/7Pj33Jo@UE0DLXQ8qxzHawRsy3e65UTF0j74U5pOnZlBVlrS9U8HJ4ZU9rC515p8d2oUrIzAxdj0dKugHzCv@IYGM4yuso4ueqt98Qt9sDvbCJc@3TTixPf0GHiYxQnvu3mEfGf@5RNuW6MGE8gyAFTlzJo1U/V1MKSXM1yh4V03cVCzm5fxs3VggclLCFo3zUPx4@gIoRpggoJL8DfTGcPJw5PwF/3x/bE5WWzqWxntFvK@uEX)

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 39 bytes

```c
f(n){n=n%100<60&n/100%100<60&n/1e4<24;}
```

Checks hours.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZDPboMwDMbveQorE1Oi0jXlTyUKtLc9wW4dh8rAGqkLUwiVuopnZ4FtNPXF38@OPyfB5QfiMNRM8ZvKlbcWItuIZ7WywoEqyoIo7YcnqfDclRVkrSll83LaESKVgc@jVOzSyJKTGwEbY9HgoYB8wt/iGMKfZXiXcXLXG@eIvYEDbicIxdqlh16cuIYWExfDOHFtg0iIf@5TMuW60Wx8AkIOIrUpg1Z@V03NDPLVLA@i4La7WPDZ7UvbuZpRr4QleO27ov74EVj4ME1gwWEP9E135nSlsAX6ejy3V8r/NuvKdFrZpaQffgA)

Answer (score 1):

### [MUMPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MUMPS), <del>74 70 64</del> 40 bytes

```
t(t) s l=$l(t)-5 f f=l:2:7 q:$e(t,f,f+1)>$s(f-l:59,1:23)
 q f>5
```

Ah, I didn't consider that you only need to handle values up to 239999. That drops it from 64 to 40.

```
t(t) f f=$l(t)-3:2:7 q:$e(t,f)>5
 q f>5
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ṚHÐoṀ<6
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RZAxTgNBDEWvsuVGCsL27oxiCUWUtJQcAIooaKWIhi5Kg0RFHcENuECkdFG4R3KRYXa@PdvszJ9n@3v/6nm9fk/pctg/nL6Gy2F7F9P5eH/d/V633y@b4bXJZ/M25OPnfNzcnj4yevz7zN8Vipqb5QifUmpbmjdBZ/Omjfmm5caUr4xXHp8Z79KNQLpgKhZlrC@sN9YX1oMFpeISTMGpehU3ouA6QhsPC2yzCK4jtHO1bZ2rbWx7Yb74fMF88flCDM7OGdz/Gf7i/gJ/cX@Bv7i/wD8f4Ip@9X5Fv3q/ol@9X6d4pnwQyJSQR0S1hq2Gaw1bDXuNBUk1SbIoqWZJFibVNMnipJpnZz/clZrZPw)**

#### How?

```
ṚHÐoṀ<6 - Link: integer, n                 e.g.  236059
Ṛ       - (implicit digits of n) reversed        [9  , 5  , 0  , 6  , 3  , 2  ]
  Ðo    - apply to odd indices:
 H      -   halve                                [4.5, 5  , 0  , 6  , 1.5, 2  ]
    Ṁ   - maximum                                6
      6 - six                                    6
     <  - less than?                             0
```

---

[Alternative 7](https://tio.run/##RZBBagMxDEWv4uUEUippxkMEpfQKXfYA7SIkBEI33YVuAjlCaW6QAzSQXUnvMbmI6/GXPJuxv5@kr/nL19XqI6Xh/DX8HNYynHcPfbpenm6fp9vu@227WYd8hvdNPo7Xy/b@d5/R898hf5coCnePI3xJqWloHqLO5qHp803LjSlfGa88PjPepR2BtNFUX5SxrrDOWFdYBxaViks0BafqVdyIouse2nhcYJtFdN1DO1fb1rnaxrYX5ovPF8wXny/E4Oycwf2f4S/uL/AX9xf4i/sL/PMBruhX71f0q/cr@tX7dYpnygeBTAl5RFRr2Gq41rDVsNdYkFSTJIuSapZkYVJNkyxOqnm29sNtqZn9Aw):

```
ṚḊm2Ṁ<6 - reverse, dequeue, modulo-2-slice, maximum, less than 6?
```

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 56 bytes

```
param($a)!(1-in(0..2|%{$a%100-ge60;$a/=100})-or$a-ge.24)
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##NcjdCoIwFAfw@z3FSc7Cga6zpYLEoDeJXcwKNGVddDF99rUZ3fw/fsv8cf79cOMYcTAhLtbbqUQrDqWqn6@SpNQrD2i5IqrvrqML2pNJZxP17NEmk7oRcWOMKlAVtH0FXZ60RxKVSWVre9ozgz7/Wv2HbnLDCjwwAPRg4Ag4wPWWboG@YBuLXw).

Answer (score 1):

## [ArnoldC](https://lhartikk.github.io/ArnoldC/), 676 bytes

```
IT'S SHOWTIME
HEY CHRISTMAS TREE n
YOU SET US UP 0
GET YOUR ASS TO MARS n
DO IT NOW
I WANT TO ASK YOU A BUNCH OF QUESTIONS AND I WANT TO HAVE THEM ANSWERED IMMEDIATELY
HEY CHRISTMAS TREE s
YOU SET US UP 0
GET TO THE CHOPPER s
HERE IS MY INVITATION n
I LET HIM GO 100
ENOUGH TALK
HEY CHRISTMAS TREE m
YOU SET US UP 0
GET TO THE CHOPPER m
HERE IS MY INVITATION n
HE HAD TO SPLIT 100
I LET HIM GO 100
ENOUGH TALK
HEY CHRISTMAS TREE o
YOU SET US UP 0
GET TO THE CHOPPER o
HERE IS MY INVITATION 60
LET OFF SOME STEAM BENNET m
ENOUGH TALK
GET TO THE CHOPPER o
HERE IS MY INVITATION 60
LET OFF SOME STEAM BENNET s
KNOCK KNOCK o
ENOUGH TALK
TALK TO THE HAND o
YOU HAVE BEEN TERMINATED
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rZI9a8MwEIZ3/Yp36@oMLXSU7UskbEmu7hzjsbRjE0Pz/3FPDaUEEkihixB3D/e8@nj9PC4f72/r6uWBwS5N4gMZRzMalz1LsAzJRDiaOY1gEoyMcUBldrrXWoZlZRKCzaxYm@AFMU3GY7JRSstyV1BY1GNsHNIWLyOx@BQZNrb4RZ3dE8RR0DpPlEmbIVDrrVA/X0t2uppMR@kUZdMwUFbI6Sx4Rpjh496LLXbN69Er7nzALmFTVYZiGncOYvvumu5wj@5wU6eQs23heej1oorxrxGWeyIsNyI8VabY0nYLToHAQjagphi1erhQ/9fUk@liajqc1@XCUZYfiStf4Xy4729QE0UI5eCjvn67rpvH5y8)

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 25 bytes

port of [Neil's solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200126/80745)

```powershell
$args-match'[6-9].(..)?$'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZBbC4JAEIXf91dMsJVCihYGi0RB7xX1GBFqUxLaZS8UmL/d1jJy92nmnPMdmL1dH8hFillW0SNMoKhoxE/CySOZpP3t2GE713Jde0r7VUnIzCIDiwVs7A2AHqNMoK2FepFcfWa/NQestZiI7xmQ18Z8g/NNMGAGGTAjPBwZgg0v6EJBoH70ovIYuTbxecNE4kHfS/eNyVGoTGqlp/@hiX6t7WozV0Je82V81thuVsBGJQkKodOdH@jg/V8cwvpX1/ghLD6VtfIth5KU1Rs)

Accepts input from 0 to 239999 and outputs `$null` for times and the input for non-times.

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), <s>42</s> 39 +1 (-p) = 40 bytes

```perl
$_=0|!($_%100>59|$_/1e4%10>5|$_/1e5>23)
```

Saved 3 bytes by changing to exponent notation (1000 => 1e4)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3tagRlFDJV7V0MDAztSyRiVe3zDVBMizM4WwTe2MjDX//zc0NLU0tfyXX1CSmZ9X/F@3AAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
твà60‹
```

Only works for the range \$[0, 235959]\$.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//YtOFTYcXmBk8atj5/7@ppZkBAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W90eK7NuS3ap@eUVdorKTxqm6SgZF/5/2LThU2HF5gZPGrY@V/nf7ShjpmBjqEBEANpI2MDEAFimYBYJkCWqaUBiICoMgCTILaphQGYBLMtwWyQGiOwGiOwGiMDQzAbbDJYvRFYvRFYvRFYvSVY3BIsbgkWt0TYBaEgPEMIzxDMg1huALHdAGK9AcR@Y4jhQMrUIhYA).

**Explanation:**

```python
тв      # Convert the (implicit) input-integer to base-100 as list
  à     # Pop and push the maximum
   60‹  # Check if it's smaller than 60
        # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 40 bytes

```powershell
param($n)($n%100-lt60)-and($n%1e4-lt6e3)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/vyCxKDFXQyVPE4hVDQ0MdHNKzAw0dRPzUsACqSYggVRjzf///1uaWpoZAAA)

Comment: @mazzy I could also use `-and`. Thanks for the reminder

Comment: also you can use `*` instead `-and` in this case. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/vyCxKDFXQyVPUxtIqBoaGOjmlJgZaGqBeakmIF6qseb///8tTS3NDAA "PowerShell – Try It Online")